# How to implement a python code to work as Azure Function?

Tags: python, sockets

I have built a Socket TCP / IP server that listens on a specific port and then, with that data, makes a rest query to another server, and that response is returned through the port where it received it.
All Socket server is made in Python 3.8 and works great.
I need to know how to implement this code from my Socket server to an Azure Functions, so that it provides permanent service?
I appreciate the goodwill of anyone who can offer an answer.

Thanks Total.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: you cannot do that. Azure Functions are Event-based (such as an HTTP call). If you need to provide TCP socket, maybe hosting your python code in a container, e.g. Azure Container Instances, might be a good way to go.

Comment: Hi Silent.

I have taken his advice and adapted it to my circumstance. We have the project in a Virtual Machine, so I transformed my python project into executable (our VM is Windows), I have added it to the system startup and it has been working as needed.
Thank you very much for your guidance, it helped me to unblock my thinking.

Greetings and thanks .... total.

Comment: ok glad to hear it. Please accept the answer then. Just be aware that running VMs means you have to manage those (patching, backups, failover etc.)